# How to execute insert command inside perl script?

Tags: sql-server, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use DBI;

use Data::Dumper;
use Asterisk::AGI;
my $agi = new Asterisk::AGI;


my $extension  = '8315';  
my $cti  = '7702009896';  
my $service_id =1;


my $DSN = q/dbi:ODBC:SQLSERVER/;
my $uid = q/ivr/;
my $pwd = q/ivr/;

my $DRIVER = "Freetds";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$uid,$pwd) or die "Coudn't Connect SQL";


my $sql3=(qq{
                declare '@' + callnumber as int
                set '@' + callnumber = $callnumber
                set '@' + callnumber = (Select '@'+'@' + identity)

                exec "insert into rpt_call_detail (call_start_time,call_number,call_service_id,call_step_name,call_step_type,call_step_discription) values(getdate(),'@' + callnumber,$service_id,'START',0,'CLI:' + $cli)"

          });


my $call_insert1 = $dbh->prepare($sql3);
$call_insert1->execute();
```

How to set a sql server variable inside Perl script? I want to set callnumber as @@identity I'm not able execute above code successfully.Please help me.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#last_insert_id

Comment: I want set callnumber as @@IDENTITY it is a sql server keyword where the meaning of @@IDENTITY:- Identity columns are often used to generate unique values for the primary key of a table.

Answer (score 0):

`declare '@' + callnumber as int` is not valid (MS) SQL.  You want it to say `declare @callnumber as int` instead, so after escaping the `@`, you end up with `declare \@callnumber as int`.  I'm not familiar with using `@@IDENTITY`, but assuming that part is correct, your $sql3 variable would look like:

```
my $sql3=(qq{
                declare \@callnumber as int
                set \@callnumber = $callnumber
                set \@callnumber = (Select \@\@identity)

                exec "insert into rpt_call_detail (call_start_time,call_number,call_service_id,call_step_name,call_step_type,call_step_discription) values(getdate(),'@' + callnumber,$service_id,'START',0,'CLI:' + $cli)"

          });
```